# ActiveRecord less_than_or_equal_to validation error on equal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have defined this ActiveRecord validation

```
validates :attr_1, numericality: {
    less_than_or_equal_to: :attr_2,
    message: "...",
    allow_nil: true,
  }, if: [proc { |a| a.attr_2.present? }]
```

which seems to work fine generally, but I'm getting a false positive in one case where `attr_1 == attr_2`.

I tried to debug the issue printing the values inside the message and putting a log message like this

```
validates :attr_1, numericality: {
    less_than_or_equal_to: :attr_2,
    message: "%{value}, %{count} - ...",
    allow_nil: true,
  }, if: [proc { |a| Rails.logger.info "#{a.attr_1} <= #{a.attr_2} -> #{a.attr_1 <= a.attr_2}" ; a.attr_2.present? }]
```

and an error is raised with this message

```
9531.28, 9531.28 - ...
```

furthermore, in the logs I see

```
9531.28 <= 9531.28 -> true
```

How could it be possible?

Edit:
I saw that the values to compare are [parsed as number](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/45511fa8b20c621e2cf193ddaeb7d6fbe8432fea/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L89) before, but the result seems to be the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured out what's happening. Basically, the issue is related to a bug which was present on ActiveModel validations well described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26085), that has been solved [here](https://github.com/GRESB/gresb-reports/pull/7354) and released in [version 5.2.3](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v5.2.3).

If you're far behind this version as I do and don't want to upgrade, I suggest implementing your own validator extending `ActiveModel::EachValidator`, inspired by current [NumericalityValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb), and use it for each validation on numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

How are the numbers being calculated? Maybe a precission issue:

```rb
[12] pry(main)> 9531.280000000001 == 9531.280000000002
false
[13] pry(main)> 9531.2800000000001 == 9531.2800000000002
true
[14] pry(main)> 9531.280000000001 == 9531.280000000002
false
[15] pry(main)> 9531.280000000001.round(3) == 9531.280000000002.round(3)
true
```

EDIT: Added `round`

Comment: They come from user inputs

Comment: The values are both `9531.28` at the moment of comparison

Comment: No, Rails reads the value from the input and assigns it to your model's column, which probably is `BigDecimal`. Test this on a console: `m = YourModel.new(attr1: 9531.280000000001); m.attr1; m.attr1 == 9531.280000000001`, so what you see is not what you get.